# Hide UIView on view load - Xamarin iOS and MvvmCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to hide an ui element on view load. I'm using Xamarin iOS and MvvmCross (6.2.3.0). In my view, I create an uitextfield and add following binding:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
//adding uitextfield
var set - this.CreateBindingSet(MyViewConroller, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(uitextfield).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.FieldVisibility).TwoWay().WithConversion("Visibility");
}
```

And here is my viewmodel:

```
public MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
private bool _fieldVisibility;
public bool FieldVisibility
{
get {return _fieldVisibility;}
set {
SetProperty(ref _fieldVisibility, value);
}

public override Task Initialize() {
FieldVisibility = false;
}
```

But when the view is loaded, my uitextfield is still visible. I tried to call RaisePropertyChanged, but it didn't help:

```
private bool _fieldVisibility;
    public bool FieldVisibility
    {
    get {return _fieldVisibility;}
    set {
    SetProperty(ref _fieldVisibility, value);
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FieldVisibility));
    }
```

It works, when I change some other viewmodel property and simply call:

```
private string _otherProperty;
        public string OtherProperty
        {
        get {return _otherProperty;}
        set {
        SetProperty(ref _otherProperty, value);
FieldVisibility = false;
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FieldVisibility));
        }
```

but I'd like to have this uitextfield hidden on view load. Can you suggest any solution for that? I'd be very grateful for any hint. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have strongly typed bindings nowadays for stuff like this:

```
set.Bind(uitextfield).For(v => v.BindVisible()).To(vm => vm.FieldVisibility);
```

You don't really need the visibility converter here, should work without it.

Remember to also call `Apply()` on your binding set.

Also `TwoWay()` won't do anything here, because there are no Binding Targets which allow for Two Way bindings for UIView visibility.